Composer alias not working on MacOS - command not found: php
I'm migrating from Windows to Mac but can't setup my working environment for php development. I've installed Xampp on MacOS and now trying to install composer but the alias is not working at all. First, I added php to the path
sudo nano ~/.zshrc

Added this to file and save
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin

PHP is now working
source ~/.zshrc
php -v
PHP 8.2.4 (cli) (built: Apr  6 2023 04:12:41) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Next I downloaded and installed composer as their website instructs. Moved composer to /usr/local/bin/composer. I can now execute this command
php /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar -V
Composer version 2.8.2 2024-10-29 16:12:11
PHP version 8.2.4 (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-8.2.4)
Run the "diagnose" command to get more detailed diagnostics output.

Next I tried to create an alias for composer by editing the zshrc file again. It now looks like this
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
alias composer=”php /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar”

Now I try this command and it fails
source ~/.zshrc
composer -V                                 
zsh: command not found: ”php


You should be using regular quotes ("), not fancy ones (”).

Yup, just a typo. Not even composer related. Luckily it's easily fixed ;)

Ah, I'll have to stay vigilant of mac's "smart punctuations". Thanks

Not sure, but I think it's not the MacOS keyboard driver which is going into your way here, but the program you used to edit the .zshrc file. But correct me if I'm wrong here.

I was noting down commands in Notes app for future reference and copy pasting into zsh

Your understanding of alias is correct. It looks like it's comes from the ” character instead of "

alias composer=”php /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar”

this is why you got

zsh: command not found: ”php

and not

zsh: command not found: php

Maybe try like this:

alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar"

